# Text UI not updating on *mobile* game Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a game which will be played on Android. For some reason, the UI Text is not updating on the mobile phone whilst it works well when the game is played through Unity.

The process is as follows. The users selects a mini-game he would like to play, according to his score, he will get that amount in in game money.

The starting cash amount is 20, and after playing the game on Unity one can notice that it updates (even through the inspector).
[Unity Game Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uJiN.png)

On the other hand, on mobile it doesn't update and stays the initial amount of 20.

Is this a known bug, or did I do something wrong?

Code as requested:

This is the game controller were the UI element updates:

```
public void helpAtHome()
{
    income = (5*globalMinigameScoreCounter) + income;
    Debug.Log("here");
    bankInvestment = investmentRate * income;
    money += income - bankInvestment;
    health -= 2;
    hunger -= 2;
    // bankInvestmentText.text = "€ " + bankInvestment;
    // healthText.text = "Health: " + health;
    // hungerText.text = "Hunger: " + hunger;
    // moneyText.text = "Cash: " + money.ToString();
    globalMinigameScoreCounter = 0;
}
```

Whilst this is the piece of code were the game is called and the values updated:

```
public void countDown(float timer){
    int time = (int) timer;
    timerText.text = time.ToString();
    if(time == 0){
        gameController.helpAtHome();

        gameController.bankInvestmentText.text = "€ " + gameController.bankInvestment;
        gameController.healthText.text = "Health: " + gameController.health;
        gameController.hungerText.text = "Hunger: " + gameController.hunger;
        gameController.moneyText.text = "Cash: " + gameController.money.ToString();
        gameController.globalMinigameScoreCounter = 0;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try to recreating the ui element, maybe there is a linking error or anything, but we really can't tell without seeing your code and/or your android log

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` ?
I guess you are updating text values and then opening the scene again. If you are doing so when a scene is loaded it is set to its default value. Still want to load the scene than try using PlayerPrefs.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("health",health);
gameController.healthText.text = "Health: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("health");
```

Comment: The issue is only with money, and it works well on Unity ... the issue is that it doesnt work on mobile

Comment: could you share sample project of it?